# ¿Hay algún modo para correr en "sandbox" un eval en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sandbox, seguridad

Yo sé que por años, no ha existido ninguna manera de usar `eval` en JavaScript sin conceder acceso a toda la aplicación al código ejecutado en el `eval`. 
Por lo que no es posible usar `eval` con código posiblemente no confiable. Es por ello que la opción de `unsafe-eval` existe en CSP (*content security policy*), por ejemplo.

Mi pregunta es ¿Ya existe un modo para hacer más seguro el `eval`? ¿Quizás con ECMAScript 5 o 6?

En un aplicación nueva, me gustaría permitir usuarios usar el `eval`, sin concederles todos los permisos. Lo ideal será que solo pudieran interactuar con un parte específica del DOM, y variables locales.

¿Es un sueño?

Answer (score 17):

La solución para conseguir un entorno realmente aislado podría ser la que usan herramientas online tipo http://jsbin.com o http://jsfiddle.net.

Pasa por usar **iframes** y dentro del `frame` devolver el código en una etiqueta `script` (no es necesario el *eval*). En ese caso se aplican las *políticas de mismo origen* (same-origin policy), con lo que se deberá servir el código huésped (la página web externa) bajo un dominio o subdominio **diferente** de la página invitada (la que contiene el código que se quiere ejecutar de forma aislada).

#### Ejemplo:

```
Huésped: en el dominio safe.domain.com
<html>
    <body>
    <!-- código de la aplicación huesped -->
    <iframe src="//sandbox.domain.com">
    </body>
</html>

Invitado: en el dominio sandbox.domain.com
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
             <!-- Script de origen no seguro -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

El código `script` no seguro se subiría de por parte de los usuarios una DB (por ejemplo), y se devolvería de forma dinámica desde el dominio *sandbox.domain.com* en el ejemplo.

#### Nota:

De esta forma, no se podría interactuar con el resultado del código ejecutado en el frame *invitado*.

Answer (score 5):

Propuesta **HTML5** (`IE10+`)

El atributo [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe#attr-sandbox) del elemento `iframe` nos da exactamente lo que necesitamos para ajustar las restricciones sobre el contenido enmarcado. Podemos instruir al navegador para que cargue el contenido de un `iframe` específico en un entorno de privilegios bajos.

Utilizando `sandbox="allow-scripts"` sobre un `iframe`, habilitamos al documento enmarcado la posibilidad de ejecutar `JavaScript` (pero no de crear popups).

> Cuando el documento enmarcado tiene el *mismo origen* que la página principal, se recomienda encarecidamente que no utilicemos `allow-scripts` y `allow-same-origin` al mismo tiempo, ya que esto permitiria que el documento enmarcado elimine, mediante programación, el atributo `sandbox`.

Aprovechando la [`API postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), el documento padre y el enmarcado pueden intermediar la comunicación entre ellos publicando mensajes y escuchando respuestas.

**Ejemplo**:

Archivo *index.html*:

```
<!-- Documento padre -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    textarea {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
    }
    iframe {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="codigo">
function sumar(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

sumar(1, 2);
    </textarea>
    <button id="ejecutar">Ejecutar</button>
    <iframe id="sandbox" src="sandbox.html" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
    <script>
      var sandbox = document.getElementById('sandbox');
      var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo');
      // Suscribimos al click del boton
      document.getElementById('ejecutar').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Enviamos el mensaje sin especificar el origen (*)
        sandbox.contentWindow.postMessage(codigo.value, '*');
      });
      // Escuchamos la respuesta del frame
      window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
        // Normalmente se debe verificar el origen del mensaje es de la fuente esperada
        if (evt.data && (
          (evt.origin === "null" && evt.source === sandbox.contentWindow) || 
          evt.origin === (window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host))
        ) {
          alert('Result: ' + evt.data);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Archivo *sandbox.html*:

```
<!-- Documento enmarcado -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
        // Se debe validar que el origen del mensaje sea el esperado.
        // En este caso esperamos que sea el mismo origen.
        if (evt.origin !== (window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host)) {
          return;
        }
        var resultado = '';
        try {
          resultado = eval(evt.data);
        } catch (e) {
          resultado = 'eval() arrojo una excepción.';
        }
        evt.source.postMessage(resultado, evt.origin);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

El código evaluado no tiene acceso a información sensible como *cookies*, no tiene acceso al *DOM* del documento padre, no puede cargar complementos, abrir ventanas nuevas o cualquiera de otras actividades molestas o maliciosas.

Lectura recomendada:

[Play safely in sandboxed IFrames](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) (en Ingles)

Answer (score 4):

Mozzilla está trabajando en los XPCOM, que son similares a loa COM de Windows, para permitir ejecutar ese tipo de sentencias en un [*Sandbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox) personalizado mediante la función [evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.evalInSandbox)

Mientras no esté listo, la opción más viable de momento es generar el contenido a evaluar mediante un *parsing* excesivamente restrictivo y con salida extremadamente limitada en cuanto a *tags* aceptables, pues incluso el url's e imágenes se puede agregar código ejecutable, y muy importante es el idealmente no procesar javascript, pues si se hace inserción se corre el riesgo de que se ejecute al hacer <kbd>F5</kbd>, incluso antes de ser evaluado.